# Remap RagTag Shortcuts Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I just switched to vim as my default editor and I am trying to remap the ragtag shortcuts for <%= %>, <% %> and auto-close tag to custom shortcuts:

E.g. the ragtag shortcut for <%= %> is <C-X>=. I tried to remap with:

```
inoremap <leader>, <C-X>=
```

But this just prints the = sign to the current buffer. And there does not seem to be ragtag function I could call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inoremap` disallows nested mappings, and probably C-X = is a mapping. For one time, use `imap` instead, otherwise type `imap` without argument, to know what <c-x>= maps to.